# Type 'Int32' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject' Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, int32

I have a Model, subclass of `NSObject`, looks like as below.

```
class ConfigDao: NSObject {
    var categoriesVer : Int32 = Int32()
    var fireBallIP : String =  String ()
    var fireBallPort : Int32 = Int32()
    var isAppManagerAvailable : Bool = Bool()
    var timePerQuestion : String = String ()
    var isFireballAvailable : Bool = Bool ()
}
```

I have download `NSMutableData` and made `JSON` from it using `NSJSONSerialization`.

My Code is

```
func parserConfigData (data :NSMutableData) -> ConfigDao{

        var error : NSError?
        var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as NSDictionary

        var configDao : ConfigDao = ConfigDao()

        println("Print Config \(json)")

        configDao.categoriesVer = json["CategoriesVer"] as Int32
        configDao.fireBallIP = json["FireBallIP"] as String
        configDao.fireBallPort = json["FireBallPort"] as Int32
        configDao.isAppManagerAvailable = json["IsAppManagerAvailable"] as Bool
        configDao.timePerQuestion = json["TimePerQuestion"] as String
        configDao.isFireballAvailable = json["IsFireballAvailable"] as Bool

        return configDao

    }
```

I get error

```
Type '`Int32`' does not conform  to protocol 'AnyObject'
```

where I used `Int32`.

Image Below

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Int32` cannot be automatically bridged from Objective-C `NSNumber`.

See [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-XID_45):

> All of the following types are automatically bridged to NSNumber:
>
> - Int
> - UInt
> - Float
> - Double
> - Bool

So you have to do like this:

```
configDao.categoriesVer = Int32(json["CategoriesVer"] as Int)
```

BTW, why you use `Int32`? If you don't have any specific reason, [you should use `Int`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_481).

Comment: I am using as my database have same datatype, i.e Int32 and Int16 etc.

Comment: Also can use: `... = (json["CategoriesVer"] as! NSNumber).intValue` (or any other NSNumber accessor).