# CoreData NSNumber to Int32

Tags: core-data, swift2, int32

I've read several posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26991246/type-int32-does-not-conform-to-protocol-anyobject-swift/26991672#26991672) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29446126/update-coredata-attribute-of-type-int32) and I understand the "why". None of the suggestions in these posts functioned for me, but doing the conversion a step at a time did.  This feels like a hack to me and like I'm missing something.

I've included the final bit of code here.

My Scenario:

1. Step 1: Store CoreData Object as Primitive Int32 (not shown in code)
2. Step 2: Fetch NSNumber Object (Showing just the needed code)
3. Step 3: NSNumber to Int
4. Step 4: Cast Int to Int32

   ```
   var finalQTY:Int32

   //Step 2
   if let retQTY = managedObject.valueForKey("totQty") as? NSNumber { 
   //Step 3       
   let preQTY = retQTY as Int
   //Step 4
   finalQTY = Int32(preQTY)
           }
   ```

Is there a better way? I feel like I am missing something?
(Using Int is not an option because of the size of the numbers involved. I used QTY here but that was just as an example).  Your feedback and responses are greatly appreciated as I continue to learn Swift.

Comment: Why does the "Use scalar properties for primitive data types" suggestion from http://stackoverflow.com/a/29447590/1187415 not work for you?

Comment: It does work if I change my datatype to Int.  But since I need Int32 because of the size of the variable and there is no bridging between NSNumber and Int32 it fails and I get error messages.  Thank you for looking at my question.  My solution works, it just felt off.  Going to mark this as solved and move on. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It appears there isn't a cleaner way to do this other than the two step process to get it from NSNumber to Int 32.

Thanks to everyone who pinged me on it.